# I need a regular expression that only accepts this format YYYYWWWW (e.g. 2021WW12)

Tags: regex, validation, text

I tried from https://regexr.com/ this regular expression `[1-2][0-9]{3}(WW|ww)[0-5][0-9]`.

Sample strings:

```
2021WW14
2021WW51
2021WW12
2021WW54
```

The problem here is that we only have up to 52 week number, so the regex incorrectly matches the fourth example string.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to do all of that with regex? In general it's going to end up much harder to read than if you validated the overall *structure* with regex then had actual logic for the *value*. You'd end up writing "zero to four followed by zero to nine or five followed by zero to two".

Comment: I have worked with dates and times for longer than I want to publically admit but if there is _one takeaway_ it is never EVER use regexps when you can use a proper date/datetime parsing library. They exist for _every_ programming language, and some are actually _good_.  Take advantage of existing domain knownledge---the closest you will get to a Free Lunch (TM).

Comment: Please take into account that the numbers OP tries to match **are NOT dates**. These are specific placeholders, with some static text inside. Unless you think it is an offtopic or duplicate question (then consider casting the corresponding vote), please let's get SO more welcoming for new contributors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^[12][0-9]{3}(?:WW|ww)(?:0?[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zDo5HI/2).

See the regex graph:

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[12]` - `1` or `2`
- `[0-9]{3}` - three digits
- `(?:WW|ww)` - a `WW` / `ww` string
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])` - an optional `0` and then a non-zero digit, or `1` to `4` digit followed with any single digits (`10` to `49`) or `5` followed with `0`, `1` or `2`
- `$` - end of string.